# Transitioning a div on/off screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have been working on creating a basic framework for mobile websites. I have run into an issue with transitions. I have an off-screen div that transitions to being on the screen when the menu button is clicked (top right of website). It also transitions back off-screen when the button is clicked again. This works fine as long as the overflow is not hidden.

I wish to hide the overflow, yet the div only transitions if the overflow is shown. Any ideas for the best way to handle this?

```js
    var clicked = false;
    
    function mobileNav() {
      var doc = document.getElementsByClassName("innerMenu")[0];
      if(clicked){
        if(doc.classList.contains("transitionIn")) {
          doc.classList.remove("transitionIn");
        }
        doc.classList.add("transitionOut");
      }
      else {
        if(doc.classList.contains("transitionOut")) {
          doc.classList.remove("transitionOut");
        }
        doc.classList.add("transitionIn");
      }
      clicked = !clicked;
    }
```

```css
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     font: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
     display: block;
    }
    body {
     line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
     list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
     quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
     content: '';
     content: none;
    }
    table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* FOR TESTING AND VISIBILITY */
    nav {
      background-color: #cacdce;
    }
    a {
      color: white;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    .logo {
      background-color: white;
    }
    .jumbotron {
      background-color: orange;
    }
    .content-one-left {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    .content-one-right {
      background-color: black;
    }
    .content-two-left {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .content-two-right {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    footer {
      background-color: #cacdce;
    }
    .fa.fa-bars {
      color: white;
    }
    .fa.fa-bars:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* MOBILE PAGE STYLING */
    
    .wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      height: 85vh;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    nav {
      height: 15vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .outerMenu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 15vh;
      width: 30vw;
      /* overflow: hidden; */
    }
    
    .icon {
      margin-left: 12vw;
    }
    
    .fa.fa-bars {
      margin-top: 4.5vh;
    }
    
    .innerMenu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15vh;
      right: -30vw;
      height: 40vh;
      width: 30vw;
    
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    
      font-size: 3vh;
      
      background-color: #cacdce;
    }
    
    .innerMenu.transitionIn {
      transition: 1s;
      right: 0vw;
    }
    
    .innerMenu.transitionOut {
      transition: 1s;
      right: -30vw;
    }
    
    .innerMenu > a {
      margin: 2.5vh 0;
    }
    
    .logo {
      height: 14vh;
      width: 16vw;
      margin-left: 42vw;
    }
    
    .icon {
      font-size: 6vh;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 65vh;
    }
    
    [class$="-left"] {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 50vh;
    
      display: flex;
    }
    
    [class$="-right"] {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 50vh;
    
      display: flex;
    }
    
    footer {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 15vh;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE>
    
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <title>testing</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="outerMenu">
          <a href="#" class="icon" onclick="mobileNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          <div class="innerMenu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <main class="wrapper">
        <header class="jumbotron">
        </header>
    
        <section class="content-one-left">
        </section>
    
        <section class="content-one-right">
        </section>
    
        <section class="content-two-left">
        </section>
    
        <section class="content-two-right">
        </section>
    
        <footer>
        </footer>
      </main>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Please don't post links to your executable code on 3rd party sites as those links can "die" over time and it makes it more inconvenient for us because we have to go somewhere else to fully understand your question. Just insert your code in a "code snippet", right here in your question.

Comment: Add overflow: hidden to the body tag.  Does this not produce the desired result?

Comment: playing around with the code snippet, if you remove the `position:absolute` on the `outerMenu` class (and uncomment the `overflow`), is that the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: It seems as though adding overflow:hidden to the body tag fixes the issue. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Weird i just added `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapper and the body and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scroll for the x axis for the body, then use javascript to add and hide the scroll for the outermenu on adding the transition css to the innermenu.

```js
    var clicked = false;
    
    function mobileNav() {
      var doc = document.getElementsByClassName("innerMenu")[0];
      var outermenu = document.getElementsByClassName("outerMenu")[0];
      if(clicked){
        if(doc.classList.contains("transitionIn")) {
          doc.classList.remove("transitionIn");
        }
        doc.classList.add("transitionOut");
        setTimeout(function(){
           outermenu.style.overflow = "hidden !important";
        },1000);
      }
      else {
        if(doc.classList.contains("transitionOut")) {
          doc.classList.remove("transitionOut");
        }
        outermenu.style.overflow = "visible !important";
        doc.classList.add("transitionIn");
      }
      clicked = !clicked;
    }
```

```css
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     font: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
     display: block;
    }
    body {
     line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
     list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
     quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
     content: '';
     content: none;
    }
    table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    /* FOR TESTING AND VISIBILITY */
    nav {
      background-color: #cacdce;
    }
    a {
      color: white;
    }
    a:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    .logo {
      background-color: white;
    }
    .jumbotron {
      background-color: orange;
    }
    .content-one-left {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    .content-one-right {
      background-color: black;
    }
    .content-two-left {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .content-two-right {
      background-color: gray;
    }
    footer {
      background-color: #cacdce;
    }
    .fa.fa-bars {
      color: white;
    }
    .fa.fa-bars:hover {
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* MOBILE PAGE STYLING */
    
    .wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: 1fr;
      height: 85vh;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    nav {
      height: 15vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .outerMenu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 15vh;
      width: 30vw;
      /* overflow: hidden; */
    }
    
    .icon {
      margin-left: 12vw;
    }
    
    .fa.fa-bars {
      margin-top: 4.5vh;
    }
    
    .innerMenu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15vh;
      right: -30vw;
      height: 40vh;
      width: 30vw;
    
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    
      font-size: 3vh;
      
      background-color: #cacdce;
    }
    
    .innerMenu.transitionIn {
      transition: 1s;
      right: 0vw;
    }
    
    .innerMenu.transitionOut {
      transition: 1s;
      right: -30vw;
    }
    
    .innerMenu > a {
      margin: 2.5vh 0;
    }
    
    .logo {
      height: 14vh;
      width: 16vw;
      margin-left: 42vw;
    }
    
    .icon {
      font-size: 6vh;
    }
    
    .jumbotron {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 65vh;
    }
    
    [class$="-left"] {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 50vh;
    
      display: flex;
    }
    
    [class$="-right"] {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 50vh;
    
      display: flex;
    }
    
    footer {
      grid-column: col-start / span 12;
      height: 15vh;
    }

    body{
      overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE>
    
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <title>testing</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="outerMenu">
          <a href="#" class="icon" onclick="mobileNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          <div class="innerMenu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <main class="wrapper">
        <header class="jumbotron">
        </header>
    
        <section class="content-one-left">
        </section>
    
        <section class="content-one-right">
        </section>
    
        <section class="content-two-left">
        </section>
    
        <section class="content-two-right">
        </section>
    
        <footer>
        </footer>
      </main>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```